# Encrypt multiple elements using AWS KMS

Tags: encryption, amazon-web-services

I would like to encrypt credit cards using AWS KMS.

I can encrypt the credit card number and then the exp month name ... but I can't find a way to do that in only one call (right now I have to make a call for every one of them)

Any idea or advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is to create a hash, then serialize it to transaform it into a string.
While this string can be encrypted and deserialized on decryption. Works well for simple hashes